# How to use JNI to call JAVA method from C

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I want to use JNI (Java Native Interface) to call a specific java setter method, passing a short[] buffer into it as a parameter.

Java method implimentation looks as follows:

```
public void setPcmLeft(short[] data) { pcm_l = data; }
```

From inside my C function how can I call this method using JNI.

My code currently looks like this:

```
void Java_com_companyName_lame_LameActivity_lameDecode(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{
    jclass class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jobj);

    if (class != NULL) {

        jmethodID setLeftDatatID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "<setPcmLeft>", "void(V)");
        if (setLeftDatatID == NULL) {
            LOGD("(Lame) No method setLeftData");
        }  
    } 
}
```

When I run this, the `setLeftDataID` is allays `NULL`.

Note that the `jobj` parameter is my object being passed in that contains the `setPcmLeft` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call to `GetMethodID()`, the method name does not need angle brackets, and the signature needs  to match the Java method.

```
jmethodID setLeftDatatID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "setPcmLeft", "([S)V");
```

In general, the signature is of the form `( arg-types ) ret-type`, encoded as specified in the link below. The argument is a short[], encoded as `[S`. The return type is `V` for void.

More information is available in [Chapter 3 of the Oracle JNI guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp1064).

Comment: When do we need the angle brackets? I see some code like this `jmethodID m_mid = env -> GetMethodID(m_cls,"<init>","()V"); `

Comment: @smwikipedia - You need them in the special name `<init>`, which `GetMethodID()` supports to allow reference to constructors. *"To obtain the method ID of a constructor, supply <init> as the method name and void (V) as the return type."* -- from the documentation for `GetMethodID()` in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   jmethodID midCallBack = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "setPcmLeft", "([S)V");
```

Comment: You can use one of the CallVoidMethod*() functions.

Comment: He may have used your earlier version without "[S".

Comment: Sorry I removed that comment, I made a mistake in my code. I was missing [S. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed the parameters and only noticed it after you posted yours.